# Зачем нужен разделительный твердый знак?

Tags: орфография

Мне интересно, почему нельзя всюду использовать один разделительный знак, ведь что твердый, что мягкий разделительные знаки делают одно и то же?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Согласен с автором: твёрдый знак не нужен. Как не нужна ещё тысяча вещей (например, "нн" в словах "стеклянный, оловянный, деревянный"). Традиции - это замечательно, например, конная упряжь, но причём здесь все мы? Письмо, в отличие от языка, есть нечто ПРИДУМАННОЕ, и использование здравого смысла и здесь было бы не лишним.

Comment: Здесь принято аргументировать своё мнение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделительные знаки не различаются по фонетическим позициям, а выбираются по правилу. Разделительный Ь можно считать основной формой, а разделительный Ъ  в виде исключения  пишется между приставкой и корнем, а также в сложных словах после Х. Правило выбора разделительных знаков основано на традиционном принципе русского письма.

**Зачем нам два разделительных знака?**

**Во-первых,** большинство русских приставок оканчиваются на твердый согласный, и писать Ь после твердого согласного не слишком удобно.

**Во-вторых,** разделительный Ъ  дополнительно обозначает стык корня и приставки,  а это очень удобно.   Разделительный мягкий знак  пишется  только в середине корня, поэтому мы чисто визуально различаем написания вида  **въехал и  вьётся.**  Таким образом, **дополнительная визуальная информация полезна для восприятия текста.**

**И еще о традиции.**

**Разделительный Ъ уже пытались отменить.**      «После того как орфографической реформой 1917–1918 годов буква Ъ была отменена на конце слов, разделительному твердому знаку было очень трудно удержаться в нашей орфографии. Чуть ли не сразу после реформы его стали заменять апострофом: с'ъезд, об'ём, из'ятие, и так продолжалось примерно три десятилетия. Постепенно от апострофа отказались, и буква Ъ как разделительный знак БЫЛА УЗАКОНЕНА орфографическим сводом 1956 г».

Мне кажется, **не следует делать наше письмо абсолютно унитарным, прагматичным, не берегущим никаких традиций** (к примеру, правила письма в английском и французском языках меняются редко), это тоже **национальная культура.** Поэтому в реформах желательно соблюдать золотую середину: **можно внести небольшие полезные изменения, но не следует ломать систему.**.

Comment: традиции в этом деле излишне усложняют все. Письменность это способ передачи информации. Никто ведь не пользуется пленочным фотоаппаратом в дань традициям. Все предпочитают использовать более совершенный инструмент. И здесь все так же. Я все равно не понял, зачем они ввели твердый знак, почему не использовали мягкий, чтобы избавиться от лишней буквы? Идея с апострофом хороша, но это не буква. К тому же апостроф имеет собственное применение, его можно использовать вместо ковычки, так что это все-таки плохой вариант.

Comment: Утилитарным....

Comment: УНИТАРНЫЙ, . Направленный к объединению, единству чего-л.; служащий объединению. У-ая теория. У-ые устремления, тенденции.УТИЛИТАРНЫЙ, Имеющий практическое назначение.  Я имела в виду "унитарный, то есть одинаковый, единообразный).

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы только отчасти.
С точки зрения смыслоразличительной функции вполне можно использовать один знак, случаев, когда выбор знака определял бы семантику слова, не зафиксировано.

Но фонетический и морфологический принцип русской орфографии предопределяют сохранение разделительного твердого знака как самостоятельной графемы. Во-первых, это наглядное отделение приставки от корня, во-вторых, твердый знак в отличие от мягкого не означает смягчение предшествующего согласного звука, т.е. с позиций фонетики разделительные твердый и мягкий знаки "делают" совсем не одно и то же.

Кроме того, твердый знак может встречаться и не только как разделительный, а еще и в корне заимствованных слов.

Comment: Насчет фонетического принципа не соглашусь. Например, слово вьюга можно произнести как с мягким в, так и с твердым. Слово подъезд тоже некоторые произносят с мягким д, хоть там и стоит твердый знак. Ну а слово адъютант хоть и пишется с твердым знаком, но произносится всегда с мягким д. Таким образом, единственная причина использовать Ъ это просто демонстрация места, где кончается приставка и начинается корень. Но в этом нет никакого практического смысла, ведь буквы не для этого придумывались.

Comment: @LaoZzzi Подождите, в слове "вьюга" - а) мягкий В б) не выделяется приставка.  Вот вам и "практический смысл". Вы теперь знаете и правильное произношение и морфологию слова. )))) Но вообще говоря, подобная утилитарная трактовка как "практический смысл" в целом чужда русской орфографии. Есть понятие "принципов орфографии", основной  из них - морфологический, есть еще несколько - фонетический, дифференционный, традиционный. Иногда к ним добавляют еще некоторые, но никак не "практический смысл".

Comment: Написание разделительного твердого знака в той или иной мере отвечает трем из перечисленных, кроме  дифференционного. А что такое "практический смысл":? Остальные суждения я не комментирую, ибо они лишены целевой составляющей: непонятно, что из всего этого следует. Что касается адъютанта, то лично я не вижу большой беды в замене в этом слове  (и только в нем!) твердого знака на мягкий, хоть это и противоречит традиционному принципу. Это не будет реформой орфокрафии в целом, которую вы предлагаете.

Comment: Если букву можно убрать и не получить при этом проблемы в правильном понимании и чтении слов, значит, в этой букве нет практического смысла. Ведь смысл букв в том, чтобы передавать звучание и смысл слова. Я не предлагаю реформ, я пытаюсь угадать, как будет развиваться русский язык. Мне кажется, что в будущем люди откажутся от использования твердого знака.

Comment: *Если букву можно убрать и не получить при этом проблемы в правильном понимании и чтении слов* - Любую букву можно "убрать", дело привычки. Но это никак нелбзя назвать отсутствием практического смысла. Но если букву "убрать" то это и будет **реформой** орфографии. Тут уж позвольте использовать общепринятое толкование, а не то, что вы там "предлагаете". Прогнозы на будущее позвольте обойти стороной, сейчас никаких предпосылок к тому нету. Главное препятствие - морфологический принцип, если уж совсем точно то не он сам по себе, вытекающие из него положения.

Comment: Наоборот, есть все предпосылки к более широкому его использованию. Часть из них вошла в предложения орфографической комиссии, остальное осталось за скобками, но по-прежнему актуальна (предЪыстория, инЪяз и проч.)

Comment: ужас какой) предъыстория, хаха) По-моему, эти комиссии просто пальцем в носу ковыряют, не зная, что бы им выдумать эдакого)) Даже если они скажут, что правильно писать предъыстория, никто так писать все равно не будет, потому что это глупость несусветная, лепить в слова лишние буквы, без которых вполне неплохо обходились все это время)

Comment: А по-моему - это кто-то другой ковыряет. )))

Comment: @LaoZzzi "thought" -> "sot" и так далее. Марк Твен об этом уже писал.